# TikZ: Flow chart errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, flow-charts

I modified the flowchart code given [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) a bit, to produce this:

[image]

This is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=yellow!20, 
    text width=6em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{small_block} = [circle, draw, fill=white!20, 
    text width=0em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em]    
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {\textbf{START} \\ Randomly generate $n$ groups of $p$ strings.};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Choose the leader string for each group.};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (mutate) {Mutate each string according to the given rule.};
    \node [block, below of=mutate] (transfer) {Carry out parameter transfer for each group, from other groups.};
    \node [block, below of=transfer] (evaluate) {Calculate the fidelity for all the strings in all the groups.};
    \node [small_block, left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {Termination condition satisfied ?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {\textbf{STOP}};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (mutate);
    \path [line] (mutate) -- (transfer);
    \path [line] (transfer) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {No} (update);
    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {Yes}(stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Question 1:

Now, I want to get rid of the small white circle, which lies in the path of the "No" arrow. But to do that, if I delete the `\node [small_block, left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};`, I get an error: that is, the "No" arrow passes straight through the other blocks, and it looks ugly. What would be the correct way to fix this?

### Question 2:

If I modify the code further to draw a separate "START" cloud on the top of the flowchart, instead of grouping it with the "Randomly generate..." block, like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=yellow!20, 
    text width=6em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{small_block} = [circle, draw, fill=white!20, 
    text width=0em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em]    
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [cloud] (start) {\textbf{START}};
    \node [block] (init) {Randomly generate $n$ groups of $p$ strings.};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Choose the leader string for each group.};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (mutate) {Mutate each string according to the given rule.};
    \node [block, below of=mutate] (transfer) {Carry out parameter transfer for each group, from other groups.};
    \node [block, below of=transfer] (evaluate) {Calculate the fidelity for all the strings in all the groups.};
    \node [small_block, left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {Termination condition satisfied ?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {\textbf{STOP}};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (start) -- (init);
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (mutate);
    \path [line] (mutate) -- (transfer);
    \path [line] (transfer) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {No} (update);
    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {Yes}(stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Clearly, the "**START**" cloud is not appearing! Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several comments:

1. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use `\tikset{.../.style={...}}` instead.
2. Using the positioning library simplifies things a lot.
3. You get the error because the node `update` is undefined if you drop the node, but you are using it later in a path. You can just insert a coordinate.
4. There is no problem adding the cloud if you use `positioning`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=yellow!20, 
    text width=6em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
small_block/.style={circle, draw, fill=white!20, 
    text width=0em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em},    
line/.style={draw, -latex'},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em},}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Randomly generate $n$ groups of $p$ strings.};
    \node [cloud,font=\bfseries,above=1cm of init] (start) {START};
    \node [block, below=of init] (identify) {Choose the leader string for each group.};
    \node [block, below=of identify] (mutate) {Mutate each string according to the given rule.};
    \node [block, below=of mutate] (transfer) {Carry out parameter transfer for each group, from other groups.};
    \node [block, below=of transfer] (evaluate) {Calculate the fidelity for all the strings in all the groups.};
    % changed to coordinate
    \coordinate [left of=evaluate, node distance=5cm] (update) {};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {Termination condition satisfied ?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {\textbf{STOP}};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (start) -- (init); 
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (mutate);
    \path [line] (mutate) -- (transfer);
    \path [line] (transfer) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    %\path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {No} (update);
    %\path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {No} (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {Yes}(stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! :) I suggested an edit to remove the redundant "START" in the (init) box and to add an arrow from the "START" cloud to the (init) box.

Comment: @Blue Thanks! (I misread the request, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

your simple flowchart is simple to draw with help of the `tikz` libraries `chains`, `positioning` and `quotes`. considering them, the code for flowchart is organized as follows:

- nodes are connected in chain with "START" on its beginning and "END" on the its end,
- lines between nodes in chain is drawn by macro `join` provided by library `chains`,
- feedback loop is drawn by use of relative coordinate for the first path's stage,
- for labeling of path is used the `quotes` library

the resulting code is much shorter and simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,       % <---
                positioning,  % <---
                quotes,       % <---
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={   % <--- named tikzset
    block/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=gray!20,
                    text width=12em, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center,
                    on chain, join=by line},
    cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, minimum height=1cm,
                    on chain, join=by line},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, draw, fill=green!30,
                    text width=6em, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center,
                    on chain, join=by line},
     line/.style = {semithick,-Triangle}
                            }% end of styles
     }% end of tikzset
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 8mm,
  start chain = going below
                    ]
% Place nodes
\node [cloud,font=\bfseries] (start) {START};
\node [block] (init)        {Randomly generate $n$ groups of $p$ strings.};
\node [block] (identify)    {Choose the leader string for each group.};
\node [block] (mutate)      {Mutate each string according to the given rule.};
\node [block] (transfer)    {Carry out parameter transfer for each group, from other groups.};
\node [block] (evaluate)    {Calculate the fidelity for all the strings in all the groups.};
\node [decision] (decide)   {Termination condition satisfied ?};
\node [block] (stop)        {\textbf{STOP}};
% Draw edges o included with "join" macro
\draw[line] (decide.west) to ["No"] ++ (-1.5,0) |- (identify);
\path       (decide) to ["Yes"] (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]